# using wxpython How to get words I type in one Textctrl panel to appear encrypted in the other and vise versa

Tags: wxpython

```
y = list(jumble)
x = list(alphabet)
self.button1.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OkButton)
self.button2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.YnButton)
i = 0

def OkButton(self, e ):
    global str1
    for i in range(len(x)):
    f1 = x[i]
    f2 = y[i]
    i += 1
    str2 = str1.replace(f1,f2)
    str1 = str2
    self.result.SetLabel(self.editname.GetValue())

def YnButton(self, e):
    global str1
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
    f1 = x[i]
    f2 = y[i]
    i += 1
    str2 = str1.replace(f2,f1)
    str1 = str2
    self.result.SetLabel(self.editname.GetValue())
```

Here I Bind `button1` to `OkButton` and `button2` to `ynButton` , what suppose to happen is when I type a word in the first panel it should appear in the second one encrypt and then decrypt again.

Comment: You are going to have to get to grips with a) posting "all" the relevant code and b) sorting out the indentation in the posted code. Until then we would be simply guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import wx

class MyWin(wx.Frame):
    """
    Creates the GUI
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None, title="My Enigma Machine", style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE & ~(wx.RESIZE_BORDER | wx.MAXIMIZE_BOX))
        #### Widgets
        ## Panel
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        ## Buttons
        self.buttonEncript = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Encript')
        self.buttonDecript = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Decript')
        ## TextCtrl
        self.tcToEncript = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="", size=(515, 22))
        self.tcToDecript = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, value="", size=(515, 22))
        #### Sizers
        self.sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(1, 1)
        self.sizer.Add(self.tcToEncript,     pos=(0, 0), border=2, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.buttonEncript, pos=(0, 1), border=2, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.tcToDecript,     pos=(1, 0), border=2, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.buttonDecript, pos=(1, 1), border=2, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL)
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.sizer.Fit(self)
        #### Bind
        self.buttonEncript.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnEncript)
        self.buttonDecript.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnDecript)

    #### Methods of the class
    def OnEncript(self, event):
        """
        Encript the text. It will just change the case of each letter
        """
        string = self.tcToEncript.GetValue()
        stringEncripted = string.swapcase()
        self.tcToDecript.SetValue(stringEncripted)

    def OnDecript(self, event):
        """
        Same as OnEncript
        """
        string = self.tcToDecript.GetValue()
        stringDecripted = string.swapcase()
        self.tcToEncript.SetValue(stringDecripted)       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyWin()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```